# Is it possible to hover an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I want to hover on elements of my webpage automatically using JavaScript so that the hover effects is visible. Is it possible?

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

I want to hover one of the links without user interaction.

Comment: Please show the code example and your try .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a CSS class for the hover effects, you can both use the traditional CSS `:hover` pseudoselector to get normal hover effects. But you can also manually add another trigger class to apply the same stylings.

```js
const links = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.link-hover' ));
document.querySelector( '#toggle_hover' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  links.forEach( link => link.classList.toggle( 'active' ));
});
```

```css
.link-hover:hover,
.link-hover.active {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a class="link-hover" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="link-hover" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="link-hover" href="#">Link 3</a>

<button id="toggle_hover">Toggle hover</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be done by using pure CSS:

```css
.link:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Link 3</a>
```